# Eclipse RCP crashes on Ubuntu 16.04 with SIGABRT in gdk_display_open() when using Desktop.open(...)

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp, ubuntu-16.04

We have recently made a cross-platform build for one of our Eclipse RCP applications. On Ubuntu 16.04, when the following code is executed:

```
Desktop.getDesktop().open(somePath.toFile())
```

It crashes with SIGABRT in gdk_display_open. I had used both Oracle's JVM and OpenJDK (JRE 8) to the same effect.

I thought, okay, let me try this first and disable the functionality if it isn't supported:

```
public static boolean isSupported()
{
    return Desktop.isDesktopSupported() &&
        Desktop.getDesktop().isSupported(Desktop.Action.OPEN);
}
```

That crashes in the exact same way. I cannot seem to even ascertain that Desktop is supported via code without the potential to cause a crash. The code I am using works fine otherwise in Windows and even Mac. Why might this happen and is there a workaround for it? Keep in mind this isn't a plain old Java exception that I can catch, this crashes in the JVM itself.

Comment: A workaround might be to try using the SWT `Program.launch` which has a similar function.

Comment: That did the trick for now: In the context of Eclipse, `Program.launch` was indeed the easiest workaround (the other workaround I found involved adapting parts of this: https://github.com/jjYBdx4IL/github-utils/blob/master/src/main/java/com/github/jjYBdx4IL/utils/awt/Desktop.java). I'm sticking with `Program.launch` for now.

Answer (score 0):

Set this environment variable to prevent loading a mixture of Gtk2 and 3:
export SWT_GTK3=0